# Is it possible to create file list in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I would like to create a file list that like the following:

[image]

As long as I input multiple files into a section, it will make a LIST that contents the files.

Is there any nodejs module or javascript to do that in Electron?

Comment: [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/)

Answer (score 0):

It is just simple problem that means only you need to do is creating list of files(it can be object or array on application) and using methods to put elements as well. Print it to screen. It is done.

I don't know how to provide you an correct example. However I think you can make view like Photo you provided in question by using tables elements from library you using.

Below is one of popular UI library Bootstrap as you know.

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/

[image: Bootstrap table docs]

Also getting array of current directory can be done with `fs.readdirSync`.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readdirSync('.') // OUTPUT (Windows Node v10): [ 'node.exe',
  'nodevars.bat',
  'node_etw_provider.man',
  'node_modules',
  'node_perfctr_provider.man',
  'npm',
  'npm.cmd',
  'npx',
  'npx.cmd' ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still wish there's a file list module (or others) that can provide more functions such as resizing column, dropping file at the section to input file, etc.

Comment: I think it is just all for library tasks. It is actually part of design and visual functional. Array or Object is just used to handle data in backend and function.